# How can I use a for loop in PHP to return mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an app that will list employees by a certain store in a listview. My current function in my DB_Functions.php file is:

```
public function getEmployeeList($name) {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE name = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $employee_list = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        if (empty($employee_list)) {
            return NULL;
        } else {
            return $employee_list;
        }
    }
}
```

and in my employees.php file I have the following code:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array('error' => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $employee_list = $db->getEmployeeList($name);

    if ($employee_list != false) {
        $response['error'] = FALSE;
        //EMPLOYEE LIST OBJECT HERE
    } else {
        $response['error'] = TRUE;
        $response['error_msg'] = 'No employees have been added to this profile.';

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = TRUE;
    $response['error_msg'] = 'You have not logged in to your store\'s account, please log in first.';

    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

I would like to have an employee_list object in the commented space above. Something like:

```
$response['employee_list']['0'] = $employee_list['0'];
$response['employee_list']['1'] = $employee_list['1'];
$response['employee_list']['2'] = $employee_list['2'];
```

etc... etc...

After that JSONObject is returned to the android app, the contents will be listed in a listview. I would need a for loop (*I think*) because the employee number will never be known since each store will be able to add and remove employees as they wish. Can someone point me in the right direction and also advise if I am using the correct approach as far as the rest of the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in your DB_Functions.php, you should be returning the mysqli_result object.
Hence your DB_Functions should be this:

```
public function getEmployeeList($name) {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE name = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // we get the mysqli_result object without calling the fetch_assoc() on it
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();

        // if the count is less than 1, no result found, hence return null
        if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // we return the mysqli_result object without calling the fetch_assoc() on it
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

In your employees.php, what you want is something like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array('error' => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $result = $db->getEmployeeList($name);

    // do an early check for if result returns null or is not set
    if (is_null($result) || !$result) {
        $response['error'] = TRUE;
        $response['error_msg'] = 'No employees have been added to this profile.';
    } else {
        $response['error'] = FALSE;
        //EMPLOYEE LIST OBJECT HERE
        // since $result->fetch_assoc() returns one row at a time, you want to loop through each row and get the appropriate data
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // inject the current into the employee_list array
            $response['employee_list'][] = $row;
        }
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = TRUE;
    $response['error_msg'] = 'You have not logged in to your store\'s account, please log in first.';
}

// echo response gets called no matter what
echo json_encode($response);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much!! +1. I managed to get the results into the app, I can see it in the log like this:
{"error":false,"employee_list":[{"employee_name":"Jason Matthews"},{"employee_name":"Tori Wilson"}]}
Now, I just have to figure out how to put all of that in a selectable list. Thank you very much for your help.